# Trying to make a basic sliding puzzle game in java but running across a problem when trying to test

Tags: java

I am currently trying to make a basic sliding puzzle game. However, I am kind of stuck and not too sure on what I need to do to fix my problem.

Here is my code below and when trying to test out what I have so far, the method CreateTheGame is not working?
I get the following error in my tester, "the method CreateTheGame in the class Sliding Puzzle cannot be applied to given types: Required: int[][]"

Did I mess up pretty bad or is it a simple mistake? Thanks!

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class SlidingPuzzle
{
public static int rows = 4;
public static int cols = 4;
private int EmptyBox;
public static int[][] TheGame;

public SlidingPuzzle(int row, int col)
{  
    rows = row;
    cols = col;
    int[][] TheGame = new int[row][col];

}

**public static void main (String[] args) {

    CreateTheGame();

}**


public static int[][] CreateTheGame(int[][] TheGame)
{
   //Created an array to use to generate random numbers
   //that'll be filled into the 2D array
   Random random = new Random();
   int[] TheNumbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
   int count = 0;


   for (int x = 0; x < TheNumbers.length; x++) {
           int ranIndex = random.nextInt(TheNumbers.length);
           int Temp = TheNumbers[ranIndex];
           TheNumbers[ranIndex] = TheNumbers[x];
           TheNumbers[x] = Temp;   
   }

   for (int row = 0; row < TheGame.length; row++)
    for (int col = 0; col < TheGame[row].length; col++)
   { 
       TheGame[row][col] = TheNumbers[count];
       count++;   
   }
   return TheGame;
}

public void printGame () 
{ 
   for (int row = 0; row < TheGame.length; row++)
   for (int col = 0; col < TheGame[row].length; col++)
   {
       System.out.print(TheGame[row][col] + " ");
   }
    System.out.println();

}   

//public int SelectBoxToMove();
```

Comment: `CreateTheGame()` does not pass in the required argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better if you call the `CreateTheGame()` method inside the constructor and you need to add an int[][] argument `TheGame` in your case so it will be like this `CreateTheGame(TheGame)`.
After int the main method you create an instance of `SlidingPuzzle`like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

SlidingPuzzle game= new SlidingPuzzle(4,4);
```

}

Comment: Thanks so much! I am still learning Java and so I decided to make a kind of basic version of the sliding puzzle haha. Now I am able to get back on track!

Comment: Good luck, keep up you are doing great!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like CreateTheGame() requires an argument of type int[][].

But when you call the function here, you do not pass it any argument:

```
**public static void main (String[] args) {

    CreateTheGame();

}**
```

Perhaps you meant something like `CreateTheGame(TheGame);`

Comment: I did what you suggested and it made more sense to me haha. I also ended up moving that into the constructor, suggested by Mehdi. Now everything seems to be back on track, thanks!